# Issue getting mac address in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I tried to get mac address of my visitors on my website.

I'm using `getmac` from NodeJS but it gets the mac address of my server, and I'd like to get something unic of the visitor.

Would I get the IP ADDRESS or the MAC ADDRESS ? And which module can I use ?